# Filter array of numeric PIN code strings which may be in the format "######" or "### ###"

Tags: php, arrays, regex, filtering, numeric

I have a PHP array of strings. The strings are supposed to represent PIN codes which are of 6 digits like:

```
560095
```

Having a space after the first 3 digits is also considered valid e.g. `560 095`.

Not all array elements are valid. I want to filter out all invalid PIN codes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can make use of regex for this.

PHP has a function called [**preg_grep**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to which you pass your regular expression and it returns a new array with entries from the *input* array that match the pattern.

```
$new_array = preg_grep('/^\d{3} ?\d{3}$/',$array);
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
^     - Start anchor
\d{3} - 3 digits. Same as [0-9][0-9][0-9]
 ?    - optional space (there is a space before ?)
        If you want to allow any number of any whitespace between the groups
        you can use \s* instead
\d{3} - 3 digits
$     - End anchor
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a regular expression to make sure there are 6 digits with or without a space.

A neat tool for playing with regular expressions is [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)... here's what RegEx I came up with:

```
^[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3}$
```

It matches the beginning of the string `^`, then any three numbers `[0-9]{3}` followed by an optional space `\s?` followed by another three numbers `[0-9]{3}`, followed by the end of the string `$`.

Passing the array into the PHP function `preg_grep` along with the Regex will return a new array with only matching indeces.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate over the valid responses (loop over them), you could always use a [`RegexIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php):

```
$regex = '/^\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/';
$it = new RegexIterator(new ArrayIterator($array), $regex);
foreach ($it as $valid) {
    //Only matching items will be looped over, non-matching will be skipped
}
```

It has the benefit of not copying the entire array (it computes the next one when you want it).  So it's much more memory efficient than doing something with `preg_grep` for large arrays.  But it also will be slower if you iterate multiple times (but for a single iteration it should be faster due to the memory usage).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of the valid PIN codes, use [codaddict's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428669/php-filter-array/4428690#4428690).

You could also, at the same time as filtering only valid PINs, remove the optional space character so that all PINs become 6 digits by using [`preg_filter`](http://php.net/preg_filter):

```
$new_array = preg_filter('/^(\d{3}) ?(\d{3})$/D', '$1$2', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer might depend on your situation, but if you wanted to do a simple and low cost check first...

```
$item = str_replace( " ", "", $var );

if ( strlen( $item ) !== 6 ){
echo 'fail early';
}
```

Following that, you could equally go on and do some type checking - as long as valid numbers did not start with a 0 in which case is might be more difficult.

If you don't fail early, then go on with the regex solutions already posted.